# Writing a function that checks whether a word is comprised of just letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def isAllLetter(word):
    letters='AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz'
    for char in word:
        if char not in letters:
            return False
    else:
        return True
    
print(isAllLetter('DrJava1'))  ----> Output: False
print(isAllLetter('Python'))   ----> Output: True
print(isAllLetter('C++'))      ----> Output: False
```

Hello, I have written a function which checks whether a word is only made up of letters. That is, it must not have any punctuations, numbers, etc. I have used here for-else statement, but I also want to learn different methods to solve it, which don't use any special functions or using tuples, lists and dictionaries, thanks.

Edit:
I was just wondering if there is a method using more basic methods to solve this question like for-while loop, string operations, etc. My teacher is so obsessive, so I do not know whether she allows me to use for-else.

Comment: What do you mean _"without being used any special functions or using tuples, lists and dictionaries"_? You don't use any of them here.

Comment: Ahh, Stack Overflow. There was absolutely no reason to close this guy's question.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi A string is technically an array of characters, which basically is a list in Python AFAIK

Comment: @Zock77 If you can guess what the actual question is, can you please edit this into an articulation which is suitable for reopening? ("Please solve this problem in many other ways with no clearly defined success criteria" and "Please review my code" are both unsuitable; see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic))

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a method using more basic methods to solve this question like for-while loop, string operations, etc. My teacher so obsessive, so I do not know whether she allows me to use for-else.

Comment: @Zoe Strings are iterable in Python, which is why you can iterate over them and treat them like lists (yay duck typing!), but _strings are strings_, not lists.

Comment: Obsessive about what? Why would `for`/`else` be problematic? You can actually take out the `else:` as you only fall off the end of the loop if you didn't `return False` from inside.

Comment: so, there is no more basic method to solve it. I need to solve it by using for-else, right?

Comment: This teacher wants us to solve the questions in such a way that she taught us in lesson.

Comment: @blitz1 if you have questions for your teacher, _ask your teacher!_ We don't know what more basic technique you want. We don't know what way you were taught in your lesson.

Comment: I explained what I want in the question explanation(using basic for-while method or string operations). Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)

> Return `True` if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, `False` otherwise.

```
def isAllLetter(word):
    return word.isalpha()

>>> isAllLetter('DrJava1')
False
>>> isAllLetter('Python')
True
>>> isAllLetter('C++')
False
```

If you weren't allowed to use the built-in method for some reason, a sequence of ascii letters is available

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

You can iterate over using `all` to short-circuit upon finding the first character outside that set

```
def isAllLetter(word):
    return all(i in ascii_letters for i in word)
```

Comment: These solutions show that you have a deep knowledge about py library and operations, but I actually search more basic methods, such as just using for-while loop, string operations etc. In this case, is using for else statement only way for me to do it?

Comment: @blitz1 You seem to have your own definition (or maybe your teachers?) about how "basic" or "advanced" a solution is. I'd consider both of these simple as they are literally one line, and use the Python standard library. I'm not sure how much more simple the code could get.

Comment: We are just taught elementary python library functions in lessons.  Not spesific functions like isalnum() etc. But anyway, thanks for help!